# Can a file divide anything smaller then 8bits?

Tags: 64-bit, ntfs, ext4, binary-files, posix

Short Question:

- What is the smallest unit savable to a file?
- What is the smallest divisible unit of a file?

Long Question:

I've been looking through the internet, trying to find out if I can access a bit directly in a file. Everywhere I look it seems you need to read the file one byte or word at a time, and then apply a bit filter to get the result.

Does this mean that a file on a 64bit-word POSIX OS cannot contain file sizes that do not divide 8bits? This creates the question if I have a corrupted file that only saved halfway how much of a buffer do I have around the file to access the data? Can each part of a fragmented file only divide 8bits or even 64bits, on a 64bit OS?
If I write a program to read binary, will there be any undefined behavior I have to watch out for? E.g. going out of bounds before EOF or something.

Comment: Even though getc and putc exist they are mainly, and illusion.  For efficiency the hard drive actually reads in the whole sector perhaps more, and caches it assuming you will want it later.  The more spare memory you have the higher the probability its secretly caching the whole file.

Comment: Further even if you could force the OS to read 1 bit at a time the performance would be so horrible you would be forced to stop using it.  In linux you can force the bonnie++ to read 1 sector at a time, but the performance is soo much worse(factor of 10+) than letting the OS handle it than nobody uses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the smallest unit savable to a file?

1 bit (but not really. It depends on your filesystem and hardware, see below.)

> What is the smallest divisible unit of a file?

1 bit

Almost no files would ever be intended to be accessed this way, but that's a subject of file-formats and implementation in various software and hardware.  But if you open any file up in a hex editor you could technically alter just one single bit of data (change a 07 to a 08, for example). Some hex editors will give you the binary representation as well, which makes it even easier to flip single bits from 1 to 0 or back.

> Everywhere I look it seems you need to read the file one bite or word at a time, and then apply a bit filter to get the result

This depends on the exact programing language you are using, but yes, most of them work at the byte level rather than bit because it's simply easier. Not to mention the OS' and hardware usually don't operate at the bit level either... so the programing language needs to take that into account. A notable exception, however, is boolean values such as `true` and `false`. Many languages store boolean values as a single bit, binary `1` for `true` and binary `0` for `false`. Another notable exception is integers and floating point values, which count in binary under the hood of most languages. But for strings, each character is going to use up a whole byte, at least. Up to 4 bytes for 32-bit Unicode encoded characters.

As a rule, however, the way you write your application code is several steps removed from the "ONs" and "OFFs" it is ultimately made of and will be compiled into. This is because the whole purpose of the compiler is to let you write abstract, human readable code that it then turns into actual machine instructions. It's a feature, not a bug.

> Everywhere I look it seems you need to read the file one byte or word at a time, and then apply a bit filter to get the result

Files are a completely different can of worms. Here it is your storage media and the filesystem you use that determines your minimum file-size. It depends on what sector size the file system was configured with and what the minimum sector size the storage media supports is. it can be 64, 128, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, or even 16384 bytes. If you write a file containing 1 bit of data to a file system using 4096 byte sectors then the file will take up 4096 bytes (or 4 KiB), despite containing 1/32768th that much actual data.

This is done because dealing with small sector sizes creates additional work for the storage device and the filesystem... but larger blocks make less efficient use of space. It's a trade off between space efficiency and performance. Older hard drives typically have a 512 byte physical sector forcing you to use 512, 1024, 2048, 4069 byte (etc..) sectors. Optical media (CDs and DVDs) typically use 2048 byte sectors. And modern hard drives are physically designed for 4096 byte sectors. Space efficiency isn't as big a deal as it was when hard drives could only hold 1 gigabyte (oh the memories).

Of note, being on a 64-bit os has no effect on any of this. 64-bit refers to how the operating system and the applications running on it address memory (ie RAM). Not storage space. See your programming language's documentation regarding variables and data types to learn more about how it handles 32-bit and 64-bit environments differently.

> This creates the question if I have a corrupted file that only saved halfway how much of a buffer do I have around the file to access the data?

When you figure that one out be sure to publish a paper on it, create a data recovery company, and become filthy rich. In the meantime, every data recovery business out there has an opinion on the matter and none of them appear to be any more clearly correct than another. The "short" answer is: depends on the filesystem and the storage media (plus the exact, yet unknown state of the read/write proccess at the moment of the failure).

Generally, magnetic storage devices like hard drives write whole sectors at the time... so each whole sector is theoretically written at once. I'm not able to remember if flash media does the same at the moment or not. Must be getting old.

> Can each part of a fragmented file only divide 8bits or even 64bits, on a 64bit os?

Actually, fragmentation, by definition, is when a single file's sectors are scattered around the hard drive. Interestingly, the effect that this has when a file has small parts of it changed is that various sectors that the file is occupying will not be entirely filled. Thus you can end up with a 32KiB file that takes up 42 KiB due to many of its sectors only being partially utilized. Modern file systems like NTFS and ext4fs take steps to prevent this, but older ones like FAT32 were notorious for it (hence why defragging used to be such a big deal). Also, as I said, storage space is no longer a rare and prized resource... so no one really cares either.

Defragmenting usually mean grabbing up all the sectors that a file is occupying and then re-writing the actual data of the file to a single empty space that can hold it, in the process eliminating all but one partially used sector.

And again, how many "bits" an OS has no effect on this.

> If I write a program to read binary, will there be any undefined behavior I have to watch out for?

Read binary from where? A file? You won't be able to do that unless you circumvent the operating system, the filesystem, and all the hardware drivers associated with controlling your storage devices and access the drive directly. This is **BAD JUJU**. Do not do this. Not to mention modern OSes and hardware are designed to treat attempts to do so as an overt security threat. Also, remember, many devices only want to write and read a certain minimum sized part for their storage at a time... and it's always more than a single bit.

Instead, you can politely ask your operating system for the smallest chunk of a file it is willing to give you via its standard APIs and then break what it gives you up into pieces from there. It will then ask the file system and the drivers which will talk to the hardware and the whole thing will get coordinated and done without you having to figure out how to do those things yourself for every single storage controller, file system, and OS ever made.

Check the API docs of the programing language and libraries you are using for details on who to accomplish that.

> E.g. going out of bounds before EOF or something.

Depends on what exactly you mean by out of bounds. There is terminology matching that in programming but it generally refers to exceeding the size of a memory buffer and writing to parts of memory your application was not allocated. This is also bad juju... but without the bold and all-caps. Mostly cause it happens so often entirely on accident that most OSes take steps to protect themselves and other applications from doing so.

However, again, when you write or read from the storage media you will be using your programming languages' and the associated libraries' APIs which will, in turn, talk to the OS' APIs, which will in turn... yadda yadda yadda. As a rule, the filesystem is responsible for making sure nothing is written where it shouldn't be and will usually send an error back along the chain to your application code if you attempt to.

Comment: Thumbs eeh vote up for a nice answer +1. Having owned an early external [ST-506](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ST-506) hard drive for the IBM-PC -  a `gigabyte` would have been a dream. The `10 megabytes` were nearly not affordable.

Comment: Flash tends to work on pages... 4KiB is a fairly safe guess, but of course it can be different. Additionally, magnetic storage will typically just write the data, whereas flash needs to erase the page (effectively resetting it all, typically to 1's) before the data can be written (typically poking out the 0's). For this reason, you'll often find that flash storage will write to a 'known erased' page, and then update a lookup table - logical no longer matches physical. This is a large part of wear-levelling, and not performing the erase as part of the write enhances performance.

Comment: It's also worth noting, that typically the smallest portion of a file that you can request is one byte. If you do so however, the OS will likely read and buffer the next _n_ bytes, because this is cheaper (enhances performance), and there is an expectation that you'll want more data soon.

Comment: note that modifying 07 to 08 would change **4 bits** at once, not only one, unless you're using some gray-code hex editor